# d3.js tree layout need to expand as nodes open, not compress

Tags: javascript, layout, tree, d3.js

I'm using the tree layout and code similar to http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

I modified it for a top down orientation.
As each node is opened/expanded, the other open nodes compress to fit everything within the SVG element.  Is it possible to prevent that? I would think modifying the x component of each node would be the approach but have not been able to accomplish that.  The nodes move over, but are still compressed together.

Also wondering how to change the linking lines from a bezier to right angles/straight lines.  Perhaps a separate question is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compression is automatic in the tree layout (and part of its point). There's no way to turn that off. However, you can simply make your SVG large enough to contain the entire expanded tree without compression. Note that this means that unless your screen is large enough scroll bars will be displayed even when everything that is visible fits onto the screen.

The links connecting the nodes are generated using the [diagonal line generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-diagonal) in the example. In principle, you can replace this with any other line generator (e.g. [`d3.svg.line`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line)), but in practice some changes will be necessary because the diagonal line generator accesses source and target nodes in a special way. For a normal line generator, you would need to convert this structure to a two-element array and for each element specify how to access x/y coordinates. Then you can use any of the interpolations to get the curve you want.

Comment: Thank you Lars.  I have created a larger 'canvas' for SVG, however, the tree graph still compresses.  It seems to take on the size of the first level down from the root/parent node and tries to stay within its size.  As for the links, I have discovered the diagonal line generator and see that it creates a path string similar to "M 100 100 C 100 150...."  I do find it confusing that it can be call with or without parameters and still produce a path.  I'll need to research it more.

Comment: You also need to set the [size of the tree layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#wiki-size) explicitly.

Comment: Oh and the parameter given to the diagonal generator is implicit, i.e. the argument you specify for `d` is actually a function.

Comment: I was incorrect about adjusting the width - it was a browser refresh issue that wasn't taking the changes. Replacing the diagonal function with a custom function appears to be the way to create custom linking lines.  As long as the function returns a string for path "M 100 100 L 100 150...." it will work.